# Find the relation between $m$ and $n$ such that the following equation has four roots.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, substitution, quartics

> Find the relation between $m$ and $n$ such that the following equation has four roots with $m > 0$.
>   $$x^2 + \left(\dfrac{mx}{m + x}\right)^2 = n$$

Well, I know what the answer is. I just want to know the complete answer.

Comment: If you know the answer you should supply it.  It can help others check their work, if nothing else.  Then, what have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Well, you add $-\dfrac{2mx^2}{m + x}$ to both sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's $$x^2-\frac{2mx^2}{m+x}+\frac{m^2x^2}{(m+x)^2}+\frac{2mx^2}{m+x}=n$$ or
$$\left(x-\frac{mx}{m+x}\right)^2+\frac{2mx^2}{m+x}=n$$ or
$$\left(\frac{x^2}{m+x}\right)^2+\frac{2mx^2}{m+x}=n.$$
Let $\frac{x^2}{m+x}=t$.

Thus, $$t^2+2mt-n=0,$$ which gives the first condition:
$$m^2+n\geq0.$$
We have:
$$\frac{x^2}{m+x}=-m+\sqrt{m^2+n}$$ or
$$\frac{x^2}{m+x}=-m-\sqrt{m^2+n}.$$
Now, just write $\Delta\geq0$ for these quadratic equations.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If  $a=\dfrac{mx}{m+x}, b=x$

as $\dfrac{b-a}{ab}=\dfrac1a-\dfrac1b=\dfrac1m, ab=m(b-a)$

Like [Solve the equation $x^2+\frac{9x^2}{(x+3)^2}=27$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2020139/solve-the-equation-x2-frac9x2x32-27/2020168#2020168),

$$n=a^2+b^2=(b-a)^2+2ab=(b-a)^2+2m(b-a)$$

which is on re-arrangement,  a quadratic eqaution in $b-a$

Comment: See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233131/how-one-should-solve-x2-frac81x2x92-40